# Write all words from text file in reverse order using a stack in c

Tags: c

I have a text file that is passed as the first command line argument, and i need to load up all of the words from the file onto a stack, and then write them back in reverse order. The words dont have to be reversed, only the order in which they were originally.

Example `Words.txt`:

> I love apples

after program finished running, `Words.txt`:

> apples love I

I wrote my code and it's not giving me any errors, but for some reason it still doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct cvor
{
    char rijec;
    struct cvor *sljedeci;
} CVOR;

void push(CVOR **tos,char rijec)
{
    CVOR *novi=(CVOR*) malloc(sizeof(CVOR));
    novi->rijec=rijec;
    novi->sljedeci=*tos;
    *tos=novi;
}

int pop(CVOR **tos,char *rijec)
{
    if(*tos==0)
        return 0;
    CVOR *p=*tos;
    *rijec=p->rijec;
    *tos=p->sljedeci;
    free(p);
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    FILE *dat;
    CVOR *tos=0;
    char rijec;
    if((dat=fopen(argv[1],"r")))
    {
        while((fscanf(dat,"%s",&rijec))!=EOF)
            push(&tos,rijec);
        fclose(dat);
    }
    if((dat=fopen(argv[1],"w")))
    {
        while(pop(&tos,&rijec))
            fprintf(dat,"%s\n",&rijec);
        fclose(dat);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char rijec;` has place for only a ***single*** character, not a null-terminated string (which needs space for *two* characters for a one-character string because of the null-terminator). What you need is some kind of array to fit the strings.

Comment: Or if you want a stack of character, then read *characters*, not strings.

Comment: If it does not work it did give you errors. There are more kinds of errors than compiler errors... But please describe in detail what you mean by "it still doesnt work".

Comment: Yes but when i try to print only one character, it prints all of the words in reverse order, letter by letter. How do i make it print strings instead of single characters?

Comment: What do you know about *strings*? What do you know about *arrays*? Please spend some to learn about these two very important concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments and the other answer pointed out, you need to store the word in your stack, not the letter. The natural way of representing a word in C is a string, i.e. a pointer to `char`, pointing to the first character of a null-terminated array. This is the standard C string format, used by `scanf()` and other functions in the standard C library.

So, the first change in your code would be the types, to probably this:

```
typedef struct cvor
{
    char *rijec;
    struct cvor *sljedeci;
} CVOR;

void push(CVOR **tos,char *rijec);

int pop(CVOR **tos,char **rijec);
```

Other points you need to change are:

- Your variable `rijec` in `main()`, it must be an array (i.e. `char rijec[N+1];`, where N is the biggest word your program will support, and 1 is the extra place is reserved for the null terminator). Unless you use compiler specific features of `scanf()`, might be tricky to support arbitrarily large words.

  - If your N=99, you must use `"%99s"` (or whatever number it is) instead of `"%s"` in `scanf()` to ensure it won't write more characters than it fits in the array (see [the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) to learn all `scanf()` capabilities).
- You must not `push()` pointer to `rijec` directly, because you will rewrite it in the next `scanf()` iteration. Instead you want to push a dynamically allocated copy of it (i.e. `push(&tos,strdup(rijec))`).

  - Conversely, after `pop()` you must call `free()` on the returned pointer, because it was dynamically allocated by `strdup()`.
  - You need a different variable whose pointer to pass into `pop()`, because it now takes a pointer of a pointer to `char`, and `rijec` is now an array, not a pointer. Something like `char *popped;` and then `pop(&tos,&popped)`, etc.
  - This is just one way of doing it, if you handle the copy and deallocation of the string inside `push()` and `pop()` respectively, so you can use the original declaration and call for `pop()`. Instead of returning the pointer, you copy the string into the array pointed by `char *rijec` argument, then you free it.
- Maybe you should use `"%s "` instead of `"%s\n"` in your `fprintf()`?

Answer (score 0):

You have written a program that inverses all characters, but not the words. In other words, I expect:

```
I love apples
```

To become:

```
selppa evol I
```

In order to solve this, I advise you, not just to make an array of all characters, but an array of words, each of them being an sub-array of characters. You read the characters and depending of the character (is it a space or not) you decide that you're still dealing with the same word or you are starting a new one.

In order to inverse, you just inverse the outer array (the one with the words), but every single sub-array (the words themselves) should be left untouched.

Comment: Yes the program does work the way you described it, but i have to reverse the order of the words using a stack, and i have no clue how to do it using that, can you give me any suggestions on how to do it?